# Bringing back value from datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am trying to use on the onSelect event to return a variable. The first part is that I am taking a date that is already in the input `$("#firstAvailable")` and doing some date formatting. Then after that, if the date changes in the datepicker, then reapply those date changes. This is not working because I have a `console.log` on my ajax and it just brings up the original date that loaded with the page. I thought the returning of the firstDate would reset the var, apparently it is not. Here is my code. Thoughts?

edit: Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stasis/JW8bZ/).

```
var date = $("#firstAvailable").val();
var firstDate = new Date(date);
var currYear = firstDate.getFullYear();
var currMonth = firstDate.getMonth();
currMonth++;
var currDate = firstDate.getDate();
var firstDate = currYear + '-' + currMonth + '-' + currDate;

$("#firstAvailable").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, uiInstance) {
            var date = $(this).val();
            var firstDate = new Date(date);
            var currYear = firstDate.getFullYear();
            var currMonth = firstDate.getMonth();
            currMonth++;
            var currDate = firstDate.getDate();
            var firstDate = currYear + '-' + currMonth + '-' + currDate;
            return firstDate;
        }
});
```

Comment: Instead of `onSelect` use `onClose`.

Comment: No luck. I changed the onSelect to onClose same thing.

Comment: Can you create an example on jsFiddle?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment.

Comment: I just put it up above in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the secondDate variable somewhere in your code.  I'm not sure which one you want to be today's date, and which one you want to be the date the user selects, but you repeatedly assign values to firstDate.

You can also use:

```
$("#firstAvailable").value = firstDate; // or secondDate
```

In order to change the value of the input.  Inside of the onSelect function you have made, you can simply write:

```
this.value = firstDate; // or secondDate
```

Comment: Here's the js fiddle with some of the needed modifications... http://jsfiddle.net/T5CsR/

Comment: I actually managed just now to figure it out Jon. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I'll post my answer shortly.